# Uploading canvas to Firebase using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

This is possibly a very simple issue—but one I'm unable to solve.

I have a canvas that I'd like to upload to Firebase as a [PNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) image. I'm not sure if I should be uploading the Base64 string, a blob, or a converted .png image.

I should say I'm reasonably new to React / Firebase, so probably making a silly mistake. Is this something that's possible to do? Should I be using a library to convert the canvas to PNG?

Some code that might be useful:

```
    // Compress image
    var canvas = document.getElementById('signature');
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 0.5);

    // Upload image
    var imageRef = ref(storage, "image.png");
    imageRef.put(dataURL);
```

The error I'm getting is:

> imageRef.put is not a function

(As an alternative, I've tried using *canvas.toDataURL* and saving that to Firebase, but the file that's uploaded is 9 bytes and is just a file containing the word 'undefined'.)

Comment: Your question should show the code (a [minimal complete reproducible example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example)) that doesn't work the way you expect. Without that, it's highly unlikely that you'll get good feedback on what's wrong and how to fix it. We should be able to copy what you have and run it for ourselves with the instructions you provide.

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson I've edited the question to add some code. The issue is that I can't seem to find 2 sources that agree on the same code at all. Happy to use my edited code as a starting point.

Comment: Your question says "but the file that's uploaded is 9B and is just a file containing the word 'undefined'."  That sounds like `put` ran but didn't do what you expect.  What's the real problem here?  Please edit to clarify.  It can't be both of these problems at the same time.

Comment: Hi, sorry for causing confusion. The 9B file was a result of using the `uploadBytes` function. I tried `putString` as an alternative, which gave the `function not found` error.